# Python резолв URI из /etc/hosts

Tags: python

У меня из скрипта на питоне отправляются данные на адрес, заданные в config.py как addr="http://addr:8080/api". В `/etc/hosts` определен IP-адрес для имени addr. Для целей логгирования, как мне преобразовать строку из config.py в строку, содержащую не имя addr, а IP из `/etc/hosts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from socket import gethostbyname
from urllib.parse import urlparse

hostname = urlparse(addr).hostname
resolved_url = addr.replace(hostname, gethostbyname(hostname))
```